# How to upload profile picture using a web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am creating a website in which the user can register an account.I want to allow them to upload image for their profile picture, but I don't know how to do this.

I have a database which holds information regarding the user, so when they want to view or edit their profile, they can do it.

I am trying to do this using the file upload control in asp.net, but by using this I can store the image in a table but I don't know how to show the uploaded image immediately to user. I doing coding in asp.net with c#. So please suggest me any solution.

Comment: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=4287517 is good example

Comment: "but I don't know how to show the uploaded image immediately to user" To have an answer to that, you need to show us the code up the upload and what is the next step that you fail.

Answer (score 3):

Images in HTML are displayed by an `<img />` element which has a `src=""` attribute which causes the user-agent to make a new request for that image resource.

The solution, therefore, is to have a request-handler for any image resources.

I assume you're using WebForms (a platform I now detest having converted to the MVC choir, but I digress). You can do this using an `.ashx` handler, like so:

```
<img src="ProfileImageHandler.ashx?userId=123" alt="Image for user 123" />
```

Your ASHX handler will have logic like this:

```
public class Handler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"; // or whatever the content-type of the image really is.

        Byte[] image = GetImageFromDatabase(context.Request.QueryString["userId"]);

        context.Response.Write( image ); // psuedo-code
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of asp.net file upload control. I am giving you a link you can refer that. Its like a walk through.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileuploadImage" runat="server" />
```

The things are explained well in this link.

> [Upload And Retrieve Image From Database](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/01/how-to-insert-images-into-database-and.html)

Please feel free to ask if you feel any difficulty.

Here is another link that you can refer.

> [Uploading Image to database](http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/04/23/uploading-and-storing-images-to-database-in-asp.net.aspx)

Comment: I know how to store uploaded image in a database.I want feature like face book,i.e user can upload their profile picture,and I want to store this in  a table so when user want to see or change their profile picture they can do it.When we upload image using file upload control,user can't see the uploaded image.I want that when user choose any image so it should get displayed in say image control,and I also can store it in database.

Comment: @AshwiniAgivale : Please share what you have done till now. So that I can work on it.